# How to create a very simple external FastCGI configuration in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

I have an externally started FastCGI application that listens on socket '/tmp/foo.sock' and a directory of static files in '/srv/static'. Apache has all needed permissions on the socket and the directories.

What I need : All requests starting with '/static' should be handled by apache using the contents of '/srv/static'. All other requests should be handled by the FastCGI application. Here is my current virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin foo@bar.com
        ServerName www.foo.com
        ServerAlias foo.com

        Alias /static /srv/static

        FastCgiExternalServer /* -socket /tmp/foo.sock    

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Even though this seems simple, its giving me quite the headache. According to http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiExternalServer the first parameter to 'FastCgiExternalServer' should be a 'filename' that when matched will cause apache to delegate the request to the external FastCGI app. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [FastCGI FAQ](http://www.fastcgi.com/docs/faq.html#FastCGIExternalServer), change the `FastCgiExternalServer` line to the belows

```
FastCgiExternalServer /srv/static -socket /tmp/foo.sock
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to FastCgiExternalServer is supposed to be some file name that
will redirect. It doesn't have to exist.  It doesn't say that a wildcard is supported.
I don't think that using /srv/static is the right answer, you want that handled by Apache.